# Sourcing Anaconda Python from Hyper Terminal

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda

On Windows 10 how do I source/work in Python (installed via Anaconda) through the Hyper Terminal as opposed to Anaconda Prompt?

Answer (score 3):

You could change the shell in your Hyper settings (`Ctrl+,`), i.e. in your `.hyper.js`.

```js
// the shell to run when spawning a new session (i.e. /usr/local/bin/fish)
// if left empty, your system's login shell will be used by default
shell: '',
```

If you analyse the target of your Anaconda Prompt shortcut, it probably looks similar to this:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\Administrator\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
```

So you could just use your Anaconda Prompt within Hyper:

```js
shell: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe',
shellArgs: ['/K C:\\Users\\Administrator\\miniconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat'],
```

Works for me. After restarting Hyper, I can see my virtual environment `(base)` included in my prompt, and I can use `python` and also `conda`. I'd assume it works similar with the Anaconda Powershell Prompt, but I haven't tried it yet.